# Style for tags according to the number of occurrences

Tags: php, tags

Suppose I have an array of tags:

```
[
    ['tag' => 'hello', 'count' => 10],
    ['tag' => 'house', 'count' => 8],
    ['tag' => 'horse', 'count' => 7],
    //any number of other tag
    ['tag' => 'alone', 'count' => 1]
]
```

The number of tags is unknown, but they are sorted according to the number of occurrences (`count` key).

Now I want to apply some style (font size) to these tags, always based on the number of occurrences.
For example: the first tag will have 30px, the last tag 12px.

How can I do? The situation is complicated by the fact that I don't know the number of tags.

I do not need a final code, I need an idea to do this thing.
Thanks!

Comment: Get sum of all `count`s, then weight of some tag will be `count/sum(counts)` and adjust font size accordingly.

Comment: ...and use CSS classes rather than directly appending styles to the elements you create. This way you can modify the results later.

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder if you write a full answer, I will sign as accepted.

Comment: @RobbieAverill I want that also the sizes are variable, so I cannot use css classes, only inline style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right solution.

First of all, to change a value (`x`) from a numerical scale (`minX-maxX`) to another (`minY-maxY`), this is the equation:
`y = ((x-minX) / (maxX-minX) * (maxY-minY)) + minY`

We suppose:

- `size` is the size we want to apply to the **current** tag;
- `count` is the number of occurrences of the **current** tag;
- `maxTag` is the number of occurrences of the tag with the highest number of occurrences;
- `minTag` is the number of occurrences of the tag with the lowest number of occurrences;
- `maxFont` and `minFont` are the maximum font sizes we want to use.

So:
`y = ((x-minX) / (maxX-minX) * (maxY+minY)) + minY`
`size = ((count-minTag) / (maxTag-minTag) * (maxFont-minFont)) + minFont`

Now the PHP code is very simple:

```
    $maxCount = $tags[0]['count'];
    $minCount = end($tags)['count'];
    $maxFont = 60;
    $minFont = 12;

    foreach($tags as $k => $tag) {
        $tags[$k]['size'] = round((($tag['count'] - $minCount) / ($maxCount - $minCount) * ($maxFont - $minFont)) + $minFont);
    }
```

An example. This is `$tags`:

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'tag' => 'noombrina',
        'count' => (int) 34
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'tag' => 'comunedilanciano',
        'count' => (int) 22
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'tag' => 'lucianodalfonso',
        'count' => (int) 21
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'tag' => 'comunali2016',
        'count' => (int) 20
    ],
    (int) 4 => [
        'tag' => 'regioneabruzzo',
        'count' => (int) 19
    ],
    (int) 5 => [
        'tag' => 'forzaitalia',
        'count' => (int) 19
    ],
    (int) 6 => [
        'tag' => 'maurofebbo',
        'count' => (int) 17
    ],
    (int) 7 => [
        'tag' => 'mariopupillo',
        'count' => (int) 17
    ],
    (int) 8 => [
        'tag' => 'carabinieri',
        'count' => (int) 13
    ],
    (int) 9 => [
        'tag' => 'toniapaolucci',
        'count' => (int) 13
    ]
]
```

The result will be:

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'tag' => 'noombrina',
        'count' => (int) 34,
        'size' => (float) 60
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'tag' => 'comunedilanciano',
        'count' => (int) 22,
        'size' => (float) 33
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'tag' => 'lucianodalfonso',
        'count' => (int) 21,
        'size' => (float) 30
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'tag' => 'comunali2016',
        'count' => (int) 20,
        'size' => (float) 28
    ],
    (int) 4 => [
        'tag' => 'regioneabruzzo',
        'count' => (int) 19,
        'size' => (float) 26
    ],
    (int) 5 => [
        'tag' => 'forzaitalia',
        'count' => (int) 19,
        'size' => (float) 26
    ],
    (int) 6 => [
        'tag' => 'maurofebbo',
        'count' => (int) 17,
        'size' => (float) 21
    ],
    (int) 7 => [
        'tag' => 'mariopupillo',
        'count' => (int) 17,
        'size' => (float) 21
    ],
    (int) 8 => [
        'tag' => 'carabinieri',
        'count' => (int) 13,
        'size' => (float) 12
    ],
    (int) 9 => [
        'tag' => 'toniapaolucci',
        'count' => (int) 13,
        'size' => (float) 12
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways can be - get sum of `count`s of all tags.

Then weight of each tag will be `count/sum(count)`.

You can set **minimum font size** for minimal `count/sum(count)` value and scale it up accordingly or set **maximum font size** for maximal `count/sum(count)` and scale it down.

Answer (score 1):

greatest algorithm is :

```
<?php
    $a = 
    [
        ['tag' => 'hello', 'count' => 10],
        ['tag' => 'house', 'count' => 8],
        ['tag' => 'horse', 'count' => 7],
        //any number of other tag
        ['tag' => 'alone', 'count' => 1]
    ];

    $max = $a[0]['count'];
    foreach($a as $n => $item){

        $max = ($item['count'] > $max) ? $item['count'] : $max;

    }
    foreach($a as $n => $item){

        $a[$n]['font_size'] = 12 + floor(($item['count'] / $max) * 18);

    }
    print_r($a);
```

and the result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => hello
            [count] => 10
            [font_size] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tag] => house
            [count] => 8
            [font_size] => 26
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tag] => horse
            [count] => 7
            [font_size] => 24
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tag] => alone
            [count] => 1
            [font_size] => 13
        )

)
```

`